# Implementation of flatlist

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

i'm working on flatlist just to add simple text. i'm new in react native. Whenever I'm running the app I'm getting the same screen . i'm geeting the same screen which come bydefault in app.js . i have made one components class BasicFlatList. My code is

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, FlatList, StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import flatListData from '../data/flatListData';

class FlatListItem extends Component {
render() {          
   return (
   <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: this.props.index % 2 == 0 ? 
  'mediumseagreen': 'tomato' }}>            
   <Text style={styles.flatListItem}>
   {this.props.item.name}</Text>
   <Text style={styles.flatListItem}>
   {this.props.item.foodDescription}</Text>
    </View>
    );
    }
     }
   const styles = StyleSheet.create({flatListItem: {color: 'white',
   padding: 10,fontSize: 16,} });

   export default class BasicFlatList extends Component {
    render() {
    return (<View style={{flex: 1, marginTop: 22}}>
     <FlatList data={flatListData}
     renderItem={({item, index})=>{
     return (
     <FlatListItem item={item} index={index}>

     </FlatListItem>);
       }}>
     </FlatList>
        </View>
         ); } }

and then i made data folder in which i make a file flatListData. in this i have added the data.
```

and in index.js i have added the BasicFlatList. my code is

```
   import React, { Component } from 'react';
   import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
   import BasicFlatList from './components/BasicFlatList';

   AppRegistry.registerComponent('Flatlist', () => BasicFlatList);
```

Comment: Can you please indent your code and share the code for the file `index.js` properly? Its very difficult to understand in this way. I would be happy to help if you can do this.

Comment: yes sure i have edited my code. plz go through it now

Comment: if you are getting any problem in understanding the code then plzz do let me known

Answer (score 0):

use FlatList like this,

```
      <FlatList
        data={flatListData}
        renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
          <FlatListItem
            item={item},
            index={index}
          />
        )}
      />
```

Comment: i use this nothing happened .

Comment: i'm getting same welcome to react native screen. i even delete the app.js file .But nothing changes.

Comment: @shabnamsingh is your app name `Flatlist`

Comment: @shabnamsingh check your terminal sometimes if syntax errors occur it doesn't show up but will be visible in the terminal (metro bundler). if an error was there anything new you code in doesn't get rendered

Comment: i'm getting this error Starting the app (E:\android-sdks/platform-tools/adb shell am start -n com.flatlist/com.flatlist.MainActivity...
Starting: Intent { cmp=com.flatlist/.MainActivity }
events.js:183
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Comment: i'm not able to understand this error. i have googled it too .But Nothing works

Comment: could you send the complete error you get scroll up it should show more information regarding the error

Comment: Starting the app (E:\android-sdks/platform-tools/adb shell am start -n com.flatlist/com.flatlist.MainActivity...
Starting: Intent { cmp=com.flatlist/.MainActivity }
events.js:183
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182839/discussion-between-naveed-sheriffdeen-and-shabnam-singh).